# How to add a value to a a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing, max

I have the following list.

import datetime

```
my_list = [
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0),'0,012'], 
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0),'0,153'], 
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,114'],
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,109'],
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,252'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,012'], 
    ['Spain', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,113'], 
    ['Spain', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,116'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,250'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,266']]
```

With below code im grabbing the highest value per country. That works correct, however. I would also like to add the country to `max_price_per_list`

```
max_prices_by_country = {}
for item in my_list:
    price = max_prices_by_country.setdefault(item[0], 0)
    max_prices_by_country[item[0]] = max(price, float(item[-1].replace(',', '.')))
    country = item[0]

max_price_per_list = [[country] + [str(price).replace('.', ',') for price in max_prices_by_country.values()]]

print(max_price_per_list)
```

**This is my current output:**

```
[['Spain', '0,252', '0,266']]
```

**This is my preferred output:**

```
[[Morocco, '0,252'], 
['Spain', '0,266']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can do it this way

```py
import datetime
my_list = [
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0),'0,012'], 
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0),'0,153'], 
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,114'],
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,109'],
    ['Morocco', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,252'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,012'], 
    ['Spain', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,113'], 
    ['Spain', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,116'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,250'],
    ['Spain', 'Fish', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 17, 0, 0), '0,266']]
    
max_prices_by_country = {}
for item in my_list:
    country = item[0]

    # if country is not in dict add it with a value, 0
    if country not in max_prices_by_country:
        max_prices_by_country[country] = 0

    # get the max value of existing and incoming value (which is item[0])
    max_prices_by_country[country] = max(max_prices_by_country[country], float(item[-1].replace(',', '.')))

# convert the dict to a list of array.
max_price_per_list = [[k, str(max_prices_by_country[k]).replace('.', ',')] for k in max_prices_by_country]

print(max_price_per_list)
```

Comment: Thank you. What did you exactly do?

Comment: add some comments to my answer

Answer (score 1):

For the last part of your program it seems like you are trying to flatten the dictioray into a list.

You can do something that wont be such long command like this:

```py
max_price_per_list = list(max_prices_by_country.items())
```

Comment: What did you exactly do? This is a very powefull one-liner. Thank you.

Comment: @TangerCity 
**dict.items()**
Return a new view of the dictionary’s items (`(key, value)` pairs).
(Documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict.items))

Turning it into a list is not necessary if you're going to iterate over it. But I thought it might help since you were printing it and might want to access only one item.